# git command to clean untracked files and revert modified files in the entire working tree

Tags: git, tree

I am trying to clean all untracked files and modified file  present in the entire tree .

Ex :- `dir/sub_dir/end` is a working tree . The cwd is `end` 
When I do `git status -su` it `returns all the modified and untracked files` in the working tree.

```
git status -su
 M ../rahul.txt
?? nuke1.txt
```

Now, when I am at the top of the tree `i.e. dir directory` I want to delete the untracked files.
I did `git clean -f` but the file `nuke1.txt` is not cleaned.

So,

1. How can I clean files recursively from the top of the tree?
2. How can I clean all untracked files recursively from a inner most directory or from any directory in the tree?
3. How to checkout all the modified files to their original state?

Comment: Is `nuke1.txt` part of your `.gitignore`? If yes, you have to provide `-x`.

Comment: No , I have to clean up untracked files from the entire tree from anywhere in the tree .

Comment: Then `git clean -f` it is. What does `git clean -n` say?

Comment: git clean -f does only in the cwd

Comment: According to [git clean documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean) it _"Cleans the working tree by recursively removing files that are not under version control, starting from the current directory."_

Comment: But it doesn't clean files under a sub-directory from cwd :(

Comment: You can use the -n flag for a dry-run to see what is going to be removed. Also, it is possible that this sub-directory is in .gitignore, thus being ignored by default by this command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Cleaning files recursively from the top of the tree:

   Excluding ignored files: `git clean -df`
   Including ignored files: `git clean -dfx`

   **Important note:** I'd highly recommend you to use the `-n` flag for a dry run before running the commands above
2. According to [git clean documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean):

   > [git clean] Cleans the working tree by recursively removing files that are not
   >   under version control, starting from the current directory.

   So essentially the same answer as 1.
3. For checking out **all** files into their original state you can run `git reset --hard`. However, you should be very cautious with this command as it is irreversible, i.e. you're going to lose all your changes.

As an additional tip, I'd highly recommend you to read the following great articles that would provide you some explanation about these commands and how to use them:

1. [Undoing Changes](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/undoing-changes/) (from atlassian)
2. [Reset, Checkout, and Revert](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/resetting-checking-out-and-reverting/) (also from atlassian)
3. [Reset Demystified](http://git-scm.com/blog/2011/07/11/reset.html) (from git-scm)

Comment: 2. When I got into a directory and perform git clean -df it does not clean the files in the top dir

Comment: Which is expected, as according to the documentation the clean up is done _"starting from the current directory"_ (see full citation above).